# Man/Tree Symbiosis

Tags: story-identification

It was an old book... I'm pretty sure it was a book, and pre-1990's I think.

The basic plot was this man somehow interacted with this tree, and as a result he became a carrier of the tree's 'seed'. They were in a symbiotic relationship: the man got a much longer life, more strength, etc.; but when he did die the tree would grow up from his body.

Comment: Hmm.  First thing that occurs is the *Descolada* virus.

Comment: From Enders Game universe... yes, it does sound a little similar, but this well predates that, and the system is different.

Comment: This is not your book, but Brian Aldiss's 1962 novel 'Hothouse' features a sentient fungus which has a symbiotic relationship with animals - it sticks to their head and gives them much greater intelligence. I vaguely remember that it's explained that humans, back when humans existed, all carried this fungus, then when the climate got hotter, they lost it, and humanity reverted to a feral state.

Comment: I don't know the story, but the description made me think of the Summerisle Tree Song from The Wicker Man.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYLRRrfPJ1s

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a book, but ["Hybrid"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57902), a short story by [Keith Laumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Laumer) which was the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14021/the-great-tree-sat-upon-the-cliff-alien-i-die-soon), matches your description pretty well. It was first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, November 1961](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61340), which you can read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v021n05_1961-11_PDF/page/n3/mode/1up). You might have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?57902).

> "The Yanda have a very strange reproductive cycle. In an emergency, the spores released by the male tree can be implanted in almost any warm-blooded creature and carried in the body for an indefinite length of time. When the host animal mates, the dormant spores come into play. The offspring appears perfectly normal; in fact, the spore steps in and corrects any defects in the individual, repairs injuries, fights disease, and so on; and the life-span is extended; but eventually, the creature goes through the metamorphosis, roots, and becomes a regular male Yanda tree — instead of dying of old age."

[. . . .]

> "We made a deal. The Yanda gave me this — " Pantelle pressed a thumb against the steel bulkhead. The metal yielded.
>
> " — and a few other tricks. In return, I'm host to the Yanda spores."

[. . . .]

> Gault considered Pantelle's remarks.
>
> "What about these 'proper conditions' for the spores?" he asked
> suddenly. "You wake up and find yourself sprouting some morning?"
>
> "Well," Pantelle coughed. "That's where my part of the deal comes in. A host creature transmits the spores through the normal mating process. The offspring gets good health and a long life before the metamorphosis. That's not so bad — to live a hundred years, and then pick a nice spot to root and grow and watch the seasons turn . . ."
>
> Gault considered. "A man does get tired," he said. "I know a spot, where you can look for miles out across the Pacific . . ."
>
> "So I've promised to be very active," Pantelle said. "It will take a lot of my time, but I intend to discharge my obligation to the fullest."
>
> *Did you hear that, Yanda?* Pantelle asked silently.
>
> *I did,* came the reply from the unused corner he had assigned to the Yanda ego-pattern. *Our next thousand years should be very interesting.*

Comment: Classic KL. Sexism in the service of SF.

Comment: @RossPresser What's sexist about it? All the characters involved are male, from what I can tell.

Comment: @nick012000 "A host creature transmits the spores through the **normal mating process**" and "I've promised to be **very active**". Pantelle intends to have as much sex as he can.